# node.js async waterfall for each in array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this app that allows users to review movies, and I'm trying to add a feature that grabs the poster from the movie and displays it next to the review. I tried to do this using

query database and return list of movies =>
 [imdb-id](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imdb-id) to get the IMDB ID => [imdb](https://github.com/mhsjlw/imdb) to get the poster url => add that to a variable and compile with pug

However, I can't get it to work as the array always returns empty first before anything else runs. I've tried to use async waterfall, but I can't figure out how to loop through the array that is returned, and pass the ID to get the url

```
async.waterfall([
    function (callback) {
        console.log('Request Id:', username);
        var query = "SELECT title, rating, review FROM movies WHERE username = \"" + username + "\" ORDER BY title;";
        callback(null, query);
    }, function (query, callback) {
        // Run query on db
        connection.query(query, callback);
    }, function (rows, fields, cb) {
        // Get array of titles
        var rowArray = rows;
        console.log(rowArray);
    }
],
function(err) {
    // error stuff
})
```

Comment: Why don't you use Promises or async/await instead?

Comment: this is async, but I'll check out Promises

Comment: I am aware that this is also async, however I was speaking about the native async / await which is literally syntactic sugar for promises. I am not sure what node verison / es version you are targeting, so I can't tell you if can use it at all. If you can I can recommend you to use it, as it makes the code a lot more readable.

Comment: Oh okay. I think I'm actually going to do this with AJAX instead, it would make things a lot easier. Thanks anyways!

Comment: What? You provided node.js as tag which means you are talking about backend code here. You usually never run db queries from the frontend. Anyways I am posting an answer to explain how you could have solved it. That should help for front- and backend programming.

Comment: Well the code that I'm running grabs the reviews from the database and puts them on the page, that part works. What I ended up doing was running my code to request the images through an ajax request. So jQuery sends the titles and requests the url for the poster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use promises or the es2017 async/await instead.

Side note: The first block in your async waterfall is synchronous anyways and you don't perform any lengthy operations there. You could merge the connection.query row into it.

With async/await your code could look like this:

```
async function sendQuery() {
  console.log('Request Id:', username);
  const query = "SELECT title, rating, review FROM movies WHERE username = \"" + username + "\" ORDER BY title;";

  try {
    const rows = await connection.query(query);
    console.log(rowArray);
  } catch(err) {
     console.log(err);
  }
}
```